# How to serve DFP Interstitials for both Phone and Tablet screens

Tags: ios, admob, banner, google-dfp, interstitial

I'm using the GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.3.0 and want to serve DFPInterstitials in a universal iOS application.

Can/Should I use a single AdUnitID to serve interstitials for both the iPhone and the iPad?

If that is the case, am I correct to assume that I have to create a single AdUnit with two creative sizes (320x480 and 768x1024), and upload for each line item interstitial creatives in those 2 sizes?

Will the iOS SDK automatically load and display the correct ad size, or do I have to do something in addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around with DFP SB, it seems that it's exactly working like that:

You create an AdUnit with 2 (or 4, for landscape orientation) sizes, upload creatives for all sizes, and the correct creatives will be shown automatically.